# Evaluation of definite Integration with unknown parameter $\alpha$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x}{(x+\alpha)(x^4+x^2+1)}dx~,~~\alpha>0$

Let 
\begin{align}
I &=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x}{(x+\alpha)(x^4+x^2+1)}dx \\
&=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x}{(x+\alpha)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)}dx
\end{align}

Although we can solve it as

$$\frac{x}{(x+a)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac{A}{x+\alpha}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2-x+1}+\frac{Dx+E}{x^2+x+1}$$

\begin{align}
I &=\frac{1}{2}\int \bigg[\frac{(x^2+x+1)-(x^2-x+1)}{(x+\alpha)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)}\bigg]dx \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{(x+\alpha)(x^2-x+1)}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{(x+\alpha)(x^2+x+1)}dx
\end{align}

But it is very lengthy way

Can we solve it other then Partial Fraction Method?

Please have a look on this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can try solving it using the residue theorem, but partial fractions is quite easy and you are already on your way, so I would just use partial fractions unless you are familiar with residue theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue with

$$\displaystyle I =\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(x+\alpha)(x^2-x+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(x+\alpha)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac12I_1 - \frac12I_2 $$
where,
$$I_1 =\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(x+\alpha)(x^2-x+1)}$$
$$=\frac1{a^2+a+1}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{x+\alpha}-
-\frac12\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1}+\frac12\frac{1+2a}{x^2-x+1}\right)dx
$$
$$=\frac1{a^2+a+1}\left( \ln\frac{x+\alpha}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} +\frac{1+2a}{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1} \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}\right)\bigg|_0^\infty
$$

As a result, 
$$I_1=\frac{-\ln \alpha + \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}(2a+1)}{a^2+a+1}$$

Similarly,

$$I_2 =\frac{-\ln a+ \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}(2a-1)}{a^2-a+1}$$

Thus,

$$I=\frac12I_1 - \frac12I_2 = \frac{a\ln a}{a^4+a^2+1}
+\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt3}\frac{2a^3-3a^2+a+3}{a^4+a^2+1}$$